# Make react state available in external js script

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am using external js script which I had to place in 'public' directory of react web app. Rest of my app is in react and I need to pass argument (whole state object) from react form to that js script. How can I do that?

My folder structure:

```
-public
 -index.html
 -srcs
  -bigScript.js <- script in which I want to use state from my component
-src
 -components
  -MyComponent.js <- here is state I want to pass to script
 -App.js
```

I know I'm doing it very non-react style, and I tried to convert that bigScript into something react can handle but failed miserably. My project is small and how I implement it does not really matter, so I don't want to waste time rewriting it.

Comment: Use something like redux on top of react, then passing the state is very easy.

Comment: The most easiest way is to set the state to a variable in `window` in `render`  so that the variable gets updated when state changes and then access it from other scripts. But no one would recommend this. You can choose if you want to do this.

Comment: Although using redux is preferred way to do this, I will use `window` because I have not enough time to learn redux ;/ But the problem appears where at which point add state to `window` ?

Comment: As @Panther said: assign the state to a variable in `window` in `render` method of your component...

Comment: Yes, sorry, I thought it didn't work because it did not change anything, but the problem lies withing bigScript itself. Thanks :)